# CheckBox Tags & Codes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

In TreeView you can add a tag to the node. In a checkbox ... you can't. I found TreeViews useful because this allowed me to use the name for the "display" value and the text for additional information. Example the name as "Google" and the tag as "http://google.com".

How is it possible to do this with checkboxes? I know a checkbox accepts and object, so could I simply create a new class that allows a string and a tag, and add do it that way?

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: By the way the correct title for your question is "CheckBox Tags & Codes."

Answer (score 3):

Both [`System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) (WinForms) and [`System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) (WPF) have a `Tag` property with public `get` and `set` accessors. This is because in each case there is a base class providing such a property (in the case of WinForms it is [`Control.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) and in the case of WPF it is [`FrameworkElement.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx)).

Note that the `Tag` property is typed as an `object`. Anything that can be assigned to an instance of `object` you can assign to a `Tag` property. In particular, you could assign an instance of `string`. When you read the `Tag` property you have to cast it back to a `string`:

```
// checkBox is CheckBox
string s = (string)checkBox.Tag;
```

Alternatively, you could say

```
// checkBox is CheckBox
string s = checkBox.Tag.ToString();
```

Lastly, you could inherit from `CheckBox` and provide a `Tag` property that is typed as a `string` that hides the base implementation:

```
class MyCheckBox : CheckBox {
    public new string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 In fact this applies to any class or control derived from `Control`, not just CheckBoxes.